# How can someone prove they are 18+ by smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, nft, cryptography, privacy

Smart contracts are permission-less (no KYC) and decentralized, therefore, censorship resistant. IRL Smart contract applications range from ownership of digital paintings to proof of birth certificates, most of which would be publicly viewable metadata on the blockchain without fuss.

Well, how can they be used or designed to prove an Ethereum wallet owner is 18 years of age or older without a human-led KYC procedure, while at the same time protecting the user's privacy during the proving process?

Are there any general cryptography models applicable to this problem? Bit of a paradox right. The best answer might just be impossible lol.

Answer (score 1):

Polygon ID is the answer to your requirements.

The idea is similar to when we go to cast a vote, we don't say that I'm 18+ but government-authorized proof verifies that for us. Similarly, polygon id is based on the same idea but even more secure as it allows us to reveal only the required information.

Comment: makes no sense. `Over18` is just an attribute on a claim form, so what

Answer (score 0):

> Well, how can they be used or designed to prove an Ethereum wallet owner is 18 years of age or older without a human-led KYC procedure, while at the same time protecting the user's privacy during the proving process?

You can separate the verifier and the proof.

- The verifier does not the address that is being verified
- The consumer of the age information does see the identity documents that verified the address

Of course someone needs to verify documents at some point, there is no around this.

Comment: If there's a human reader, it's not decentralized and is in fact a traditional KYC process.

Comment: Thus, there cannot be decentralised age check process by your definition. Somewhere, someone has given you a birth and a birth certificate. That tells your birth day and any verification for your age must come from this core truth and and someone must check your document matches your identity.